# Unmounting React.js node

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to unmount a React.js node with `this._rootNodeID`

> ```
>  handleClick: function() {
>
>         React.unmountComponentAtNode(this._rootNodeID)
>
>  }
> ```

But it returns `false`.

The `handleClick` is fired when I click on an element, and should unmount the root-node. Documentation on `unmountComponentAtNode` [here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html)

I've tried this as well:

> React.unmountComponentAtNode($('*[data-reactid="'+this._rootNodeID+'"]')[0])

That selector works with `jQuery.hide()`, but not with unmounting it, while the documentation states it should be a `DOMElement`, like you would use for `React.renderComponent`

After a few more tests it turns out it works on *some* elements/selectors.

It somehow works with the selector: `document.getElementById('maindiv')`, where `maindiv` is an element not generated with React.js, and just plain html. Then it returns `true`.

But as soon as I try and select a different ElementById that is generated with React.js it returns false. And it wont work with `document.body` either, though they all essentially return the same thing if I console.log them (`getElementsByClassName('bla')[0]` also doesn't work)

There should be a simple way to select the node via `this`, without having to resort to jQuery or other selectors, I know it's in there somewhere..

Comment: (This question was also posted at https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1044 and has valuable answers there.)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Unmount components from the same DOM element that you mount them in. So if you did something like:

```
ReactDOM.render(<SampleComponent />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Then you would unmount it with:

```
ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('container'));
```

Here is [a simple JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamlacroix/JRy7W/1) where we mount the component and then unmount it after 3 seconds.

Comment: @TrySpace If you want to trigger the unmount from within the component itself, you could just pass the DOM element in as a prop and reference it when needed: [http://jsfiddle.net/iamlacroix/JRy7W/2](http://jsfiddle.net/iamlacroix/JRy7W/2)

Comment: @TrySpace In your JSFiddle above, it didn't work because you were trying to call unmount on the rendered component `#element` & not its container you used to mount it `#container`. React doesn't replace the container itself, just its `innerHTML`. This way you can always reference that container again (e.g. for re-mounting with new props, replacing with a different component, etc.)

Comment: @MichaelLaCroix what if you have list of components inside a container and would only like to remove one? Since there's only one container, calling `React.unmountComponentAtNode` on that container will remove all components. How do you get around with it?

Comment: @Marconi A top-level React component can only have one root node, so you would want to use logic based on the props or state of that component to determine whether or not a child component should be included.

Comment: @MichaelLaCroix hey thanks, but I managed last night by adding separate container for each sub component, then removing becomes easier since it has its own container.

Comment: It looks like this is deprecated for react-dom's version, but unmounting from a node that was rendered by react (which, if you're writing a single-page app, is most of them) requires you to update the parent component.
 
This is the problem I'm having with React, which is that I have to write crazy hacks for doing really basic things like creating a functioning 'close' button. Is this really the solution, that I need to add a listener to the parent component and trigger it from the child? To remove a single node? That's bonkers! 

Someone please tell me I'm missing something.

Comment: @AJFarkas Where did you get the idea that it's deprecated? [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.unmountcomponentatnode) don't mention it.

Comment: @ivarni `React.renderComponent` is deprecated as of [0.12](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/10/28/react-v0.12.html), and `React.render` is deprecated in favor of using `ReactDOM.render` as of [0.14](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html)

Comment: That's react, not react-dom.

Comment: it should be ReactDOM, better you can get ReactDOM  from your imports

Answer (score 37):

This worked for me. You may want to take extra precautions if `findDOMNode` returns null.

```
ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).parentNode);
```

Comment: This code raises an exception if Component.render returns null (Component.getDOMNode() also returns null in this case).

Comment: This code works perfectly for me. Having adding `parentNode` helps me remove entire React component.

Answer (score 6):

The example I use:

```
unmount: function() {
  var node = this.getDOMNode();
  React.unmountComponentAtNode(node);
  $(node).remove();
},

handleClick: function() {
  this.unmount();
}
```

Comment: Is the $(node) using jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to unmount the component the simple solution it's change the state and render a empty div

```
const AlertMessages = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      alertVisible: true
    };
  },
  handleAlertDismiss() {
    this.setState({alertVisible: false});
  },
  render() {
    if (this.state.alertVisible) {
      return (
        <Alert bsStyle="danger" onDismiss={this.handleAlertDismiss}>
          <h4>Oh snap! You got an error!</h4>
        </Alert>
      );
    }
    return <div></div>
  }
});
```

Comment: Render an empty div saved my day. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [the GitHub issue you filed](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1044), if you want access to a component's DOM node, you can use `this.getDOMNode()`. However a component can not unmount itself. See Michael's answer for the correct way to do it.

Comment: `a component can not unmount itself` that might be it

Comment: With react 0.14.x, this.getDOMNode has been deprecated. Please use ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.[nodeName]) for custom components or this.refs[nodeName] for supported JSX tags.

Answer (score 0):

First , i am new to reactjs ,too . Of course we can control the Component all by switch the **state** , but as I try and test , i get that , the `React.unmountComponentAtNode(parentNode)` can only unmount the component which is rendered by `React.render(<SubComponent>,parentNode)`. So `<SubComponent>` to be removed must be appened by `React.render()` method , so I write the code

```
<script type="text/jsx">

    var SubComponent = React.createClass({
        render:function(){
            return (
                    <div><h1>SubComponent to be unmouned</h1></div>
            );
        },
        componentWillMount:function(){
            console.log("componentWillMount");
        },
        componentDidMount:function(){
            console.log("componentDidMount");
        },
        componentWillUnmount:function(){
            console.log("componentWillUnmount");
        }

    });

    var App = React.createClass({

        unmountSubComponent:function(){
            var node = React.findDOMNode(this.subCom);
            var container = node.parentNode;
            React.unmountComponentAtNode(container);
            container.parentNode.removeChild(container)
        },

        componentDidMount:function(){
            var el = React.findDOMNode(this)
            var container = el.querySelector('.container');
            this.subCom = React.render(<SubComponent/> ,  container);
        },

        render:function(){

            return (
                <div className="app">
                    <div className="container"></div>
                    <button onClick={this.unmountSubComponent}>Unmount</button>
                </div>
            )
        }
    });

    React.render(<App/> , document.body);
</script>
```

Run the sample code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DaJun/kb3gN/11818/) , and have a try .

> Note: in the sample code `React.findDOMNode` is replaced by `getDOMNode` as the reactjs version problem .