# How do you remount a component in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that I need to re-mount. I need to destroy everything and make it's code re-execute to appear again on my page.

What I've tried:
I put key="1" and then with javascript changed its key to something else, it did not remount (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reactjs/8JgClU9jol0)

[Unmounting React.js node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662153/unmounting-react-js-node) this won't work because my component is already rendered.

Please help, how do I do this?

Comment: Can you expand on "destroy everything and make its code re-execute to appear again on my page"? When a component re-renders, it re-renders all of its children. What event is causing you to want to re-render? Renders in React should be driven by changes to the data or state that represent the page.

Comment: The component that you want to make appear should be the exact the same instance as the one who disappeared? Or you just need an other instance of the same class? If the second is the case, just render your component conditionally two times, in the two spots that you need them. Make the conditions that controll that rendering in such way, that when the first one fails, the second one will succeed and voila. Your component looks like dissapearing from one place and appearing to an other.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    console.log("mounted");
  }
  
  render(){
    return(
      <div>This is child</div>
    );
  }
}

class Application extends React.Component {
  state = {
    show: true,
  };
  
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({show: !this.state.show})}>Click here</button>
        {this.state.show && <Child />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```