# Fiddle not working with JSX

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle, reactjs

I was reading through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21662153/1318265) and I came across [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TrySpace/JRy7W/7/):

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var SampleComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div id='element' onClick={this.handleClick} >Mounted component.</div>;
    },
    handleClick: function() {
         alert(React.unmountComponentAtNode(event.target));
         alert(React.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('element')));
         alert(React.unmountComponentAtNode(works));
    }
});

works = document.getElementById('container');

React.renderComponent(<SampleComponent />, works);
```

It doesn't appear to be working for me even though users on the post seemed to be acting like it solved their problems.  The really weird part is that I get completely different errors on different browsers:

- Firefox: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`
- Chrome: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)`
- IE9 (not that I expected it to work anyway): `Unable to get value of the property 'triggerType': object is null or undefined`

Is this a problem with Fiddle's new layout or is there some other issue at play here?  How can I get this working in Fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Use a different Fiddle that doesn't try to load non-existent resources, e.g.,

https://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/3mv48L6j/

Also note that the pragma used in your Fiddle's JS is deprecated.

Fork and update the branch to include the functionality from your original Fiddle, making any necessary changes to be up-to-date.

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Downvotes, particularly when an answer addresses the OP's concerns, deserve commenting.