# Re render functional component on props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am unable to render updated props in functional component. However, I am able to console.log those props perfectly.

My Code:

```
class ABC extends someOtherClass {
 static create(value) {
    let node = super.create();
    node.setAttribute('style', 'font-size:100%; color: white');
    node.setAttribute('id', Date.now());
    node.onclick = function(e) {
      HandleComments({ id: e.target.id, render: e.target.id });
    };
    return node;
  }
}
```

**HandleComments Component**

```
import React from 'react';

const HandleComments = props => {
  console.log('props', props);
  return <div>{props.id}</div>;
};

export default HandleComments;
```

Comment: Add relevant code

Comment: Please add code.

Comment: Yes, you probably are missing something. Without seeing your code though, we have no idea what.

Comment: @Avanthika Just did that. Can you please take a look?

Comment: Where is your react component mounted? It looks like you are just calling a function that happens to return JSX

Comment: You can unmount a component and render it again. Not a good method but useful in bad cases. Here it's explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662153/unmounting-react-js-node

Comment: @YusufAltıparmak This is okay for Class Components but I am facing the issue with Functional Components.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `this.props.id` instead of `props.id` in functional component

```
const HandleComments = props => {
  console.log('props', props);
  return <div>{props.id}</div>;
};
```

Also you need to render the HandleComments component instead of just returning the functional instance to the onClick event like below or some other manner from someOtherClass

```
class ABC extends someOtherClass {
 static create(value) {
    let node = super.create();
    node.setAttribute('style', 'font-size:100%; color: white');
    node.setAttribute('id', Date.now());
    node.onclick = function(e) {
      ReactDOM.render(<HandleComments id={e.target.id} />, document.getElementById('root'));
    };
    return node;
  }
}
```

Comment: Still not able to render the props.

Comment: @Avanthika OP is not rendering the functional component instead just calling it and hence the render is not happening

Comment: @Avanthika on console.log, I am able to see my props.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri ReactDOM.render won't work since it's not a React Class but rather just a normal class.

Comment: In such a case its better to not follow the above pattern and simply use JSX to render elements