# How does React application unmount work under the hood?

Tags: reactjs, internals

So you mount an app like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662153/unmounting-react-js-node):

```
ReactDOM.render(<SampleComponent />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

And you unmount it like this:

```
ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('container'));
```

How does React know where the virtual DOM tree is just given the native DOM element (what kind of variables are they storing and where)?